# How to use indexPathForItemAtPoint in TableViewController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm using `PFQueryTableViewController` and in my PFQTVC.m, I've implemented `scrollViewDidScroll` method so I can get the `indexPath` of the visible cell when scrolling.

However, I get

> NO VISIBLE INTERFACE FOR 'PFQTVC' DECLARES THE SELECTOR 'INDEXPATHFORITEMATPOINT'.

`UITableViewDataSource` and `UITableViewDelegate` have been added.

What to do?

```
- (void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    NSLog(@"Did Scroll");

    CGRect visibleRect = (CGRect){.origin = self.tableView.contentOffset, .size = self.view.bounds.size};
    CGPoint visiblePoint = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(visibleRect), CGRectGetMidY(visibleRect));
    NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self indexPathForItemAtPoint:visiblePoint];

    NSLog(@"visible Index Path : %@", visibleIndexPath);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `indexPathForItemAtPoint:` method is from `UICollectionView`, not `UITableView`. You want to use `indexPathForRowAtPoint:`. And it needs to be called on the table view, not the controller.

You want:

```
NSIndexPath *visibleIndexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:visiblePoint];
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the quick answer! Anyhow, indexPathForRowAtPoint is working in my TableViewController... Nice!